# Publish automatically JavaDoc: with GitHub Actions

Tags: java, maven, github-actions, github-pages, javadoc

### Introduction

I am currently working on a Java Maven project in GitHub, and I'm building a JavaDoc and posting it to a GitHub page.

### Question

And I was wondering if it would be possible to automate this with a GitHub Actions, if so how?

Comment: this question is duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72565540/how-to-generate-automatically-a-javadoc-on-a-web-page/74804196#74804196

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### JavaDoc publisher

Yes, it is possible with this code in your GitHub Actions directory:

```yaml
name: Deploy Javadoc

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - main

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Deploy JavaDoc 
        uses: MathieuSoysal/Javadoc-publisher.yml@v2.3.0
        with:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          javadoc-branch: javadoc
          java-version: 17
          target-folder: javadoc
```

Credit: https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/Javadoc-publisher.yml
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-publish-javadoc

Add the above YAML file to `/.github/workflows/your-file.yaml` inside your GitHub repository. It publishes the JavaDoc automatically when you publish to the *"master"* or *"main"* branch. Your JavaDoc is pushed onto the *javadoc* branch, and is deployed with GitHub Pages.

***Don't forget to enable GitHub Pages on your GitHub repo settings***