# How to generate automatically a JavaDoc on a web page

Tags: java, github, github-actions, github-pages, javadoc

I am currently working on a Java project in GitHub and I need on every update to manually generate JavaDoc and upload it on GitHub Page. But it’s very tedious.

And I wondering if is possible to automatise this with a CI?

Comment: this question is duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70991706/publish-automatically-javadoc-with-github-actions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Generate automatically a JavaDoc to a web page with GitHub Page

Yes is possible, with this code on your GitHub Actions :

```yaml
name: Deploy Javadoc

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - main

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Deploy JavaDoc 
        uses: MathieuSoysal/Javadoc-publisher.yml@v2.3.2
        with:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          javadoc-branch: javadoc
          java-version: 17
          target-folder: javadoc
          project: maven # or gradle
```

Credit: https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/Javadoc-publisher.yml
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-javadoc

This code publishes JavaDoc automatically when you publish your code to *"master"* branch, your JavaDoc is pushed on *javadoc* branch, and deployed with GitHub Page.

*don't forget to enable GitHub page on your GitHub repo settings*

---

### Create a GitHub Actions inside your GitHub repository

To create a GitHub Actions you need to simply add this yaml file on `/.github/workflows/<your-file>.yaml` inside your GitHub repository.

Answer (score -1):

We can use javadoc tool:
With a maven plugin: **maven-javadoc-plugin**

```
ttys000:am ➜  ~ javadoc -d doc src\*
```

Javadoc alternatives:
**...**
**MkDocs. Free • Open Source.**
**Doxygen. Free • Open Source.**
**Slate API Docs Generator. Free • Open Source.**
**DocFX. Free • Open Source.**
**Sandcastle.**
**phpDocumentor**
**NDoc**
**DoxyS**