# GitHub Actions : How to generate and publish JavaDoc to a web page with Gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, github-actions, github-pages, javadoc

I need to generate a JavaDoc from my GitHub repository and publish it to a webpage like GitHub Page.

I found this solution on StackOverflow: [Publish automatically JavaDoc: with GitHub Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70991706/publish-automatically-javadoc-with-github-actions)

```yaml
name: Deploy Javadoc

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - main

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Deploy JavaDoc 
        uses: MathieuSoysal/Javadoc-publisher.yml@v2.0.4
        with:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          javadoc-branch: javadoc
          java-version: 17
          target-folder: javadoc
```

But this solution works only for Maven, and not for Gradle.

Someone know if is possible to adapt this for a Gradle project ?

Comment: Creating a question is a bit excitable, a simple comment to my previous answer would have sufficed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JavaDoc publisher for Gradle

Yes is possible, with this code on your GitHub Actions :

```yaml
name: Deploy Javadoc

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - main

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Deploy JavaDoc 
        uses: MathieuSoysal/Javadoc-publisher.yml@v2.3.0
        with:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          javadoc-branch: javadoc
          java-version: 17
          target-folder: javadoc
          project: gradle
```

Credit: https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/Javadoc-publisher.yml
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-javadoc

This code publish JavaDoc automatically when you publish to *"master"* branch, your JavaDoc is pushed on *javadoc* branch, and deployed with GitHub Page.

*don't forget to enable GitHub page on your GitHub repo settings*

---

### Create a GitHub Actions

To create a GitHub Actions you need to simply, add this yaml file on `/.github/workflows/your-file.yaml` inside your GitHub repository.